# Cannot find control with name: <text input control name>

Tags: angular, typescript, form-control, formgroups

I am new to Angular development and trying to have a simple form that will have 3 textual user inputs.

```
Error: Cannot find control with name: 'teamId'
    at _throwError (sources:///node_modules/@angular/forms/fesm2015/forms.js:2912:9)
```

HTML code:

```
<form [formGroup]="profileForm">
            <label>
              Tab name:
              <input type="text" formControlName="tabName">
            </label>
          
            <label>
              Team Id:
              <input type="text" formControlName="teamId">
            </label>

            <label>
              Channel Id:
              <input type="text" formControlName="channelId">
            </label>
```

TS code:

```
import { AfterViewInit, ChangeDetectorRef, Component } from '@angular/core';
import { FormControl, FormGroup } from '@angular/forms';
import { MatDialogRef } from '@angular/material/dialog';

export class MyComponent implements AfterViewInit{
    public profileForm: FormGroup;

    constructor(
        private readonly dialogRef: MatDialogRef<MyComponent>,
        private readonly changeDetector: ChangeDetectorRef,
    ) { 
        this.profileForm = new FormGroup({
            tabName: new FormControl(''),
            teamdId: new FormControl(''),
            channelId: new FormControl(''),
          });
    }

    ngAfterViewInit(): void {
        this.changeDetector.markForCheck();
    }

    public close() {
        this.dialogRef.close();
    }
```

I'm importing `FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule` in my module definition.

What is strange and not making any sense to me is that this is failing for only 1 text input-teamId (out of 3). It succeeds for other 2.

Is there anything I am missing in my code? Any help/leads will be really helpful.

Thank you.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a typo in your TS code.

In TS code you have written `teamdId` but in your html you have written `teamId`

Comment: Thanks a ton @Rahul Khunt for pointing that out!
2nd pair of eyes always help :)